# Why did SHIELD not try to recover the jet?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In Season 2, Episode 22 of *Agents of Shield*

> A quin jet with the modified crystals was pushed into the ocean by Sky

Why was no recovery attempt made?

> We see later that the crystals leaked into the ocean water. The poison was ingested by fish that were made into fish oil. This leads me to believe that many people will die or be made "inhuman".

Since the contents of the were known (at least by Sky), shouldn't Coulson have been aware as well? Why would they leave that in the bottom of the ocean?

Comment: That scene angered me a lot. Surely a recovery attempt would have been made. At the end it was just a plot device.

Comment: @flq - The answer below is quite eminently plausible, actually. I wouldn't like even S.H.I.E.L.D's chances of reversing diffusion into a whole ocean. The real plot device would be Fitzsimmons pulling out a magic element that could bind all of the crystals and render them harmless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I remember the crystals looked like they were dissolving quite quickly. There was a visible blue trail of it in the contaminated water. By the time the recovery team got there the crystals would have been dissolved and spread far to wide to capture a proportion of the water.

The less likely explanation is as the crystals have not been seen to have a lingering effected area when used so far that shield did not consider it a priority to recover them.